# How to use scriptAll to find all the <div> with id or style attributes in Karate

Tags: javascript, html, css, testing, karate

I was trying to write a test case to verify context on the page.

There are several  iterating like this

```
<form>
<div id="line1_R1" style="display:none;">text line 1 </div>
<div class="labelText nonLabelText pos y15 x1" style="white-space: nowrap; width:20.00ex;">text&nbsp;line&nbsp;1&nbsp</div>

<div id="line1_R2" style="display:none;">text line 1 </div>
<div class="labelText nonLabelText pos y16 x1" style="white-space: nowrap; width:20.00ex;">text&nbsp;line&nbsp;1&nbsp</div>
...
</form>
```

Is there a way I could extract all the string from the div whose id starting with <line1_R + index> and merge them together? Or is it possible to use  attribute instead as locator?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it, but something like this should work:

```
* def list = locateAll('form div', x => { let id = x.attribute('id'); return id ? id.startsWith('line1_R') : false })
* def data = list.map(x => x.text.trim())
```

This is the relevant documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core/#locateall-with-filter

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. This has perfectly resolved the issue.

Comment: Hi Peter, the content of this is actually cut off and across multiple pages. I have attached further details on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76301962/how-to-repeat-customized-function-with-conditional-logic-in-karate-ui. Could you please advice any solution on this? Thanks in advance.